# Definition of absoluteness in Kunen's set theory

Tags: set-theory

[image: Page 117]

In Kunens "Set Theory" the above Definiton is given. In the whole Chapter $M$ is an arbitrary class, more context is not given.

My question is:
Which definition of true is used for these formulas?
E.g. if i were to prove a formula $\Phi$ to be absolute for some $M,N$ which axioms am i allowed to use to show the equivalence? Only the axioms of logic? Or maybe ZF is meant?

[image]

This mentions a set of Sentences $S$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd interpret it as a definition schema, where you could interpret "$\phi$ is absolute for $\mathbf M,$ $\mathbf N$" as an abbreviation for the sentence $$ \forall x(x\in \mathbf M\to x\in \mathbf N) \land \forall \vec x\in \mathbf M(\phi^{\mathbf M}(\vec x)\leftrightarrow \phi^{\mathbf N}(\vec x)).$$

One could ask the same question of "what definition of true" is being used when we say "$\mathbf M$ is transitive" (also a schema of sentences, but in one formula rather than three). Generally, we are working with some reference set theory (say maybe $\sf ZF$, maybe without regularity at this point in Kunen's book), and when we work with such statements, we're allowed to use those axioms.

With that said, looking through the next couple of pages, I don't think I see anything that can't be proved just with pure logic, e.g. I don't think the theorem that syntactically $\Delta_0$ formulas are absolute or Lemma 3.7 require any set theory axioms (but I could have missed something).

Speaking of Lemma 3.7, since you asked about that too: Here, $S$ is a set of sentences in the metatheory and the statement that $S\vdash \phi\leftrightarrow \psi$ is a statement in the metatheory. Let $\sf WST$ ("working set theory") be the reference theory I alluded to earlier. What this metatheorem is saying is that if $S\vdash \phi\leftrightarrow \psi$, and $\sf{WST}\vdash\varphi^{\mathbf M}$ for each $\varphi\in S$, and similarly for $\mathbf N,$ then $\sf WST$ proves the sentence "$\phi$ is absolute for $\mathbf M,$ $\mathbf N$ iff $\psi$ is."

As I remarked above, I don't think anything other than logic is used in proving lemma 3.7, but set theory axioms will almost always be used when using it, at least assuming $S$ is not the empty set. For example, we'll often need to use the corresponding axiom $\varphi$ in $\sf WST$ to prove $\varphi^{\mathbf M}$ for $\varphi\in S,$ or need to use some set theory axioms in any event.

As Kunen mentions, the main purpose of lemma 3.7 is to transfer absoluteness for syntactically $\Delta_0$ formulas to absoluteness for formulas/concepts provably equivalent to a syntactically $\Delta_0$ formula in some set theory $S$ (or more generally, $\Delta_1^S$ concepts... those provably equivalent to both a syntactially $\Sigma_1$ and a syntactically $\Pi_1$ formula in $S$). Then this allows you to establish (schematically, in $\sf WST$) that the concept is absolute for transitive models of $S.$

So when Kunen later proves a bunch of things are absolute for transitive models of $\sf ZF-P$, or what-have-you, we're really concerned about scrutinizing $S$ rather than $\sf WST.$ Though we'll have $S\subseteq \sf WST$ here since we have $\mathbf N = \mathbf V.$ For instance one of the more important and not-altogether-trivial results is that being an ordinal is absolute for transitive models. This requires foundation since we need the equivalence of being an ordinal to being transitive and *linearly* ordered by $\in$ (rather than well-ordered by $\in$, which is the 'real' definition that works in weaker set theories).

Comment: Good catch with the transitive. So what i really should do is, is to define Z-absoluteness (where Z are the Sentences from which the equivalency is proven and from which M transitive is following) and maybe a Lemma that says that Z-absoluteness implies T-absoluteness (for Z subseteq T)?

Comment: Also 3.7 will probably most often be used with S:=Z right?

Comment: 'then WST proves the sentence "ϕ is absolute for M, N iff ψ is."' - This isnt a sentence of WST right? WST cant talk about the formulas.

Comment: @Rubids to your last question (I haven’t digested the others yet), yes it’s a sentence. The formulas are fixed, we aren’t quantifying over them in WST

Comment: Z-absoluteness would simply be a way to encode the WST=:Z into the definition of absoluteness. Because for a different WST called T more/less formulas might be absolute for M.
Or is this already how absoluteness is meant to be understood? i.e. that for different WST's we have a potentially very different formulas that are absolute for the same M and we use our results from one WST only for that WST (and not for e.g. extensions).

Comment: @Rubids In practice, it's the second (although I'm not sure what you mean by 'extensions', if you mean extensions of a theory, of course if you can prove something in one theory you can prove it in an extensions). I try to delineate this in my answer. It's not that absoluteness needs to be spoken about in reference to some theory per se (and most of the underlying machinery is pure logic), but that in order to prove absoluteness of a formula in a nontrivial case, you generally prove the classes satisfy certain axioms, and that requires some strength in WST.

Comment: thank you for this comment. As i think this is out of scope for the original question i have written a rewrite of Kunens definition here to secure my understanding:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822651/modified-definition-of-absoluteness-in-kunens-set-theory
i would be glad if you would take a look at it.