# Modified definition of absoluteness in Kunen's Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

In kunens book "Set Theory" we have [image]
and
[image]

in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821767/definition-of-absoluteness-in-kunens-set-theory) post i asked which notion of truth is used to say that the equivalency in the definition holds. It depends on which Working set Theory $W$ we use.

So for the purpose of analyzing multiple different set theorys i wanted to make it clear for myself how to rewrite this so it is clear which working set theory is used at which point and that for each different working set theory we have a different notion of absolute.

Do you think the following is a sensible rephrasing of Kunens definition in this light?

[image]

(i currently believe for Kunen this is obvious how its meant, given he is showing lots of absoluteness results for $W:=ZF^- — P — Inf$ (page 119f) and probably uses them (as in Lemma 2) to prove absoluteness results for $W:=ZF — P$ (page 126). I just want to make this very clear for myself one time)

Comment: It should of course say "$W$-absolute" in the case (2) of the definition aswell (the second time)